# How to prevent hotlinking my m3u8 live stream which created by medialive workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, m3u8, hotlinking, aws-media-live

I have built a website and live stream some private videos only to registered viewers. The live stream is generated by AWS Medialive workflow. The workflow uses Cloudfront to distribute the stream.

How could I prevent hotlinking the m3u8 cloudfront link? I have googled a lot and I only can find how to prevent S3 files hotlinking. Not sure how to do it in my case.

By the way, the live stream in my website is 24X7 live video source. Not live stream a video file.

Please help.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question has more to do with CloudFront than MediaLive.  There are ways to restrict access to a CF origin.  You can require CDN authentication for the access to CloudFront URL.

If the viewer doesn't authenticate properly through your portal, they wont have the correct cookies signed by your website, the connection will be denied.  You can also aggressively expire those cookies or URLs so any cloned copies will quickly stop working.

More information can be found at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecurityAndPrivateContent.html